# How do I befriend a template class in a parent namespace?

Tags: c++, templates, namespaces, visual-studio-2005, visual-c++-2005

I'm struggling to make my class be a friend of a template in its parent namespace.  Can someone explain what I'm doing wrong:

Here are my attempts and their errors with MSVC8 (Visual Studio 2005):

---

```
namespace a {
namespace b {

    template<typename T>
    class x;

    namespace c {

        class y
        {
            template<typename T>
            friend class x;
            ...
        };

    }
}}
```

error C2888: `a::b::x` : symbol cannot be defined within namespace `c`

---

```
namespace a {
namespace b {

    template<typename T>
    class x;

    namespace c {

        class y
        {
            template<typename T>
            friend class ::a::b::x;
            ...
        };

    }
}}
```

error C2888: `a::b::x` : symbol cannot be defined within namespace `c`

---

```
namespace a {
namespace b {

    namespace c {

        class y
        {
            template<typename T>
            friend class ::a::b::x;
            ...
        };

    }
}}
```

error C2039: `x` : is not a member of `a::b`

---

I can't just include the header file containing `class x` as it depends on `class y` leading to a circular inclusion.

Comment: [Works for me](http://ideone.com/Hm1l7), must be the compiler being dumb.

Comment: Works fine with `clang 3.1`, `g++ 4.6.2` and `VS 2008`. Can you try compiling the test program @SethCarnegie has posted in his link with MS VS 2005? Looks like a bug in the compiler ...

Comment: @SethCarnegie's test program gives me `error C2888: 'a::b::x' : symbol cannot be defined within namespace 'c'`  Not ideal.  It doesn't even work if I fully define `class x` rather than just declare it.

Comment: @thehouse have you considered updating your compiler?

Comment: @SethCarnegie: I would if I could.  It's the latest version that doesn't (accidentally-on-purpose) prevent your binary running on old versions of Windows.  One day we hope to use GCC in MinGW but not today.

Comment: @thehouse you'll have to find some workaround then, try doing a non-template class or maybe a non-template function or something, and have the template class work through that function.

Comment: @SethCarnegie: As I'm fortunuate to know all the likely instantiations of my `template<typename> class x` I hacked it by befriending each one separately (see my answer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A hack workaround: If you know the all specific types the template will ever be instantiated with, befriend each instantiation rather than the template.  For example:

```
namespace a {
namespace b {

    template<typename T>
    class x;

    namespace c {

        class y
        {
            friend class x<char>;
            friend class x<wchar_t>;
            ...
        };

    }
}}
```